# transparent JDialog becomes opaque when dragging to second screen (ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon, java 1.8.0_74-b02)

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jwindow

I created transparent JDialog which unfortunately does not work with two screens. When its dragged to other screen it becomes opaque. The code is below, just run it and drag label to other screen.

```
public class TransparentFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dialog = createDialog();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> dialog.setVisible(true));
}


private static JDialog createDialog() {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

    JLabel label = new JLabel("drag me to the other screen");
    label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> dialog.setLocation(e.getLocationOnScreen()));
        }
    });
    label.setOpaque(false);
    dialog.getContentPane().add(label);

    dialog.setUndecorated(true);
    dialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);

    dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

    dialog.pack();
    return dialog;
}
```

}

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon, java 1.8.0_74-b02

Comment: Runs fine on my three screens (running Java1.7 compliance, replaced lambdas with new Runnable() )

Comment: Did You run it on Ubuntu or other Linux?

Comment: `dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` is a bad idea, use `setOpaque` instead (you'll need to case the `contentPane` to a `JPanel` first)

Comment: dialog.getContentPane() is type of Container, it doesn't have setOpaque() method, even if it's casted to JPanel and method setOpaque is invoked, it does not help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> I created transparent JDialog

Don't know if it is a problem in this case but Swing and transparent Colors don't get along because you are breaking the painting contract between Swing and its components. Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information.

Instead of playing with transparent Colors, try using:

```
dialog.setOpacity(...);
```

Comment: Unfortunately my OS doesn't support opacity. An exception is thrown: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: TRANSLUCENT translucency is not supported" when opacity is set to value lover than 1f. Besides opacity causes all components to be transparent.

Comment: Based on [How to Implement Per-Pixel Translucency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#per-pixel), using a alpha based color for the dialogs background is correct, but it's wrong for the content pane (yeah, that's not confusing), also congrads of the 200k+!

Comment: @camickr Welcome to my every day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although this may or may not be the source of the problem, it's best to remove the shadow of a transparent window. Without these lines, my program (on Mac) would "burn" the shadows into the window display when interrupted. Although it's a single monitor setup (the MacBook screen), switching between desktops would "burn" the shadows into the window display.

`JRootPane root = frame.getRootPane();
root.putClientProperty("Window.shadow", Boolean.FALSE);`

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed with these lines added.

Comment: @WojtekWirzbicki Did you at least see the shadow disappear (if it had one to begin with)? Also it might be helpful to see an image of what's happening.